# Sorting a very large amount of json entries with the command line

Tags: linux

I have an enormous text file containing lots of json entries like so:

```
{"name":"Bob","id":1,"gender":"<gender>","height":186}
{"name":"Alice","id":4,"gender":"<gender>","height":176}
{"name":"Bill","id":3,"gender":"<gender>","height":181}
{"name":"Cathy","id":2,"gender":"<gender>","height":172}
```

I would like to sort these by their "id" value. These files are too large to fit in memory, so scripting languages don't seem like an option. Is there any way I can make use of the linux command line to solve this? I would like to get the following output:

```
{"name":"Bob","id":1,"gender":"<gender>","height":186}
{"name":"Cathy","id":2,"gender":"<gender>","height":172}
{"name":"Bill","id":3,"gender":"<gender>","height":181}
{"name":"Alice","id":4,"gender":"<gender>","height":176}
```

I've been looking into using `sort` as that seems great for dealing with very large files. However, I'm finding it difficult to instruct it to use the id value.

Comment: edit you Q to show your best guess for "using `sort`". You should be able to use something like `sort -t":" -k4,4 file` (which is ugly, and may prove to be fragile). Good luck.

Comment: `sort --field-separator=: --key=3.1 file`  works

Comment: Other comments and answers explain how to use the `sort` command, which is a good approach, *if* the id field is always in the same position on the line.  (As far as json is concerned, of course, it doesn't have to be.)  You can verify this by running `cut -d , -f 2 file | grep -v '^"id":'`.  This will print all lines where the second comma-separated filed is not an id.  If the output of that command is empty, then the `sort` approach is valid and will yield the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

> `sort --numeric-sort --field-separator=: --key=3 --temporary-directory=somedir file`

If the data needed for the process doesn't fit in memory,
then, **sort** uses `somedir` (instead of *$TMPDIR* or */tmp*).